# Komodo Edit 8.5 Tab key

Tags: php, indentation, komodo

I am new to Komodo edit but I have searched and read numerous articles and help and can't understand why when I press the `Tab` key it moves over one space as if I press the `Space Bar`??

example: (in any other program on my PC when I press `Tab` I get 5 spaces which I will represent with underscores `_`)

`Tab` should = **_____**

and `Space bar` should = _

BUT!!

in Komodo 8.5:

`Tab` = _
and 
`Space Bar` = _

and no matter what settings I have changed it stays the same 
Indent settings, settings for this file, settings for each language (php or javascript)

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found out it seems to be the opposite of what people are talking about, or what I took from what people are saying

Number of spaces per indent: 5
Width of each tab character: 1

when you first open Komodo its like 4 and 8 and I just could not get it to change I tried like 1 and 10, 5 and 10, 8 and 10 etc...

if you want the tab to work like in other programs, BIG NUMBER FIRST